# Sniffing the traffic from a TOR exit node

Tags: tor

Question regarding the traffic coming out from the TOR exit node:

I have been reading on a forum of people arguing the capabilities and risks of using TOR network. I have never used TOR before, nor would I have the need to use it, but I still want to know more about it.

I understand TOR uses randomly selected relays for traffic to travel through, but the traffic eventually comes out of an exit node somewhere. I have read that such traffic can be used to trace the user.

What i don't understand is if this traffic can be analysed, wouldn't it just show the requests are coming from the last relay instead of the original IP? Or does it show the entire trail including all the relay nodes that the traffic has passed through?

Say, this traffic can indeed be traced, does using encryption makes any difference? IF i was running an exit node (I'm not, I know the risks) and analyse the exiting traffic that is encrypted, can I still trace the original IP?

What if the user:

*is on open Wifi > connects to it with a laptop with dual NICs > is using live USB OS with say...a squid box as proxy > connects to it with another laptop > > connects to VPN > uses TOR with encryption

Is there a way for a normal user or a researcher, without ample resources like the government/law enforcement has, to still analyse the exiting traffic and trace the original IP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Since an exit relay is responsible for relaying source traffic out to the internet, if that traffic uses an unencrypted protocol (e.g. http), it *can* see the contents of that traffic.

For that reason, you shouldn't send sensitive data over Tor unencrypted when possible.  The guard (entry), and middle (relay) nodes can't see the actual traffic, only the exit can.  Only the guard node can see your true IP address.

The exit (while it can see the actual traffic and the destination) has no way of knowing your IP.  If it could, you'd be much less anonymous when using Tor.

The threats here are if an adversary controls many relays.  One of the worst case scenarios for being tracked through Tor would be if you selected a circuit where the guard node *and* exit node were controlled by the same adversary.

In this scenario, they could see your actual source IP address and your exit traffic (if unencrypted) or at the very least the destination for your exit traffic.

The other tricky part is correlating your entry traffic with the exit traffic.  Whether or not entry traffic to a relay they control is also related to exit traffic from another relay they control is strictly up to timing and traffic analysis.

To understand more, you first need to understand how Tor works on a basic level, for that see the [documentation](https://www.torproject.org/docs/documentation) page and the [overview](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en).  Then, search for things like "Tor traffic analysis", "Tor traffic fingerprinting", "Tor timing attacks", and "Tor traffic correlation" to understand more and the research being done to defend against it.

More recent versions of Tor have started padding all cells to make smaller and larger traffic indistinguishable from eachother, and much past research has been done into relay selection 
to prevent the chances of randomly selecting malicious exits or guards.

Hope that helps.